# Will http to https rewrite rule affect SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, redirects, url-rewriting, iis7

I recently started serving all my pages over https instead of http.
I did so using this rewrite rule:

```
  <rule name="force https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
```

Will this not cause me to lose link juice or affect my Google indexed pages negatively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will. The `http` and `https` version will be seen as individual pages and thus also create duplicate content.

The solution is to use a `301-permanent redirect`, which your code does. This will transfer the juice to the destination of the redirection, **so you're good**. Also, adding a `canonical tag` to indicate which is the prefered url is good practice.

There are some rumours that a redirect will cost you some value, but just the tiniest bit, nothing to worry about.

---

Might be worth mentioning that `https` has more effects on SEO. Because of the increased security you'll get a higher authority rank, which could positively effect your ranking.

`https` sites are theorically slightly slower, but in practice you will not notice this. Your implementation influences has much more effect on how much (e.g.: decrease number of resources).

Another factor will be your users. The users might trust your site more and stay longer because of that. More time on your website (often) equals a better ranking.

Comment: "HTTPS is slower" is a myth. Using HTTP/2 more than negates the SSL setup.

Comment: This answer is two years old. It was not much, but a notice amount. I shall update the answer to more current results

Answer (score 1):

Google has said they they want sites to move to HTTPS and they will even [give a slight rankings boost](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html) to sites that do so.  Your redirect rule looks like a fine way to migrate your site from HTTP to HTTPS.

Some webmasters have migrated to HTTPS recently have found that that [rankings have suffered as a result](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78820/huge-drop-50-in-traffic-after-https-move).   There is certainly some SEO risk with the switch.