# Having trouble with Google indexing after extending SSL cert across whole site and resubmitting sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index, xml-sitemap

I recently extended out SSL certification to every page on my website in an effort to gain some rank. I created and claimed the new https properties (both www and non www) in Google Search Console and then submitted a new sitemap for both the https and (the old) non-https versions as the (the old) non-https version (had a few errors).

The issue I'm having now is that both the https and non-https version are not indexing fully and after a week have only indexed 50% of my websites pages (according to Sitemaps>Indexed). Before the change last week it showed 90% of pages indexed both under Sitemaps>Indexed and Google Index>Index Status

Also curious is that under Google Index>Index Status for the https version is 0 where under Sitemaps>Indexed it's 800 submitted and 400 indexed....

Where as the Google Index>Index Status for the NON http (old) version is 1000 where under Sitemaps>Indexed it's 800 submitted and 400 indexed.

When I site (site:mywebsite.com) search for both versions I get the correct results and my position seems to be holding but I am a bit worried as web sales have been down since I implemented the change.

I've never come across and issue like this and could definitely use some guidance. After waiting about a week I'm still stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Side-note: the ranking bonus in Google is quite small. It's unlikely that you'd see that on its own.

Comment: Did you 301 redirect all http pages to https versions? Once you've moved over to https (and redirected all requests to that version), you really should only check the https version in search console.

Answer (score 1):

Your sitemap should only have **one** version of your URLs.    It sounds like you would prefer that you `https` URLs get indexed, so you should not have any `http` URLs in any of your sitemaps.

When you switch your site to HTTPS Google may take a few weeks to figure everything out.  Google had some problems with my site and others have reported similar issues.   See: [Huge drop [50%] in traffic after HTTPS move](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78820/huge-drop-50-in-traffic-after-https-move)   My only advice is to wait.   I my experience it eventually gets sorted out, but it can be painful in the meantime.