# Why my website is excluding from search results after migration to https?

Tags: google-search, 301-redirect, search-engines, https, migration

I've setup ssl certificate on my domain on 19th of February and redirected all pages to https version with 301 redirect code. From that day all of my indexed http pages are disappearing from results and no https alternative are shown instead of them. It appears that google is indexing my website as a new website and the pages are not ranked in the search engine.

When I search for my site, about 24500 pages are indexed in google but as I said none of them are shown in the search results.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it? Indeed I set up 301 redirect for all pages, none of https version of pages are replacing http version.

I've checked this question "[Are drops in Google ranking common after switching to https?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/are-drops-in-google-ranking-common-after-switching-to-https)" but the problem in this question is different from my site. In my case all of my https pages lost their rankings almost immediately.

Comment: There are too few steps detailed here for us to be able to answer this specifically, other than to suggest waiting since a dip is considered typical, and check for errors in Google's Search Console/Webmaster Tools See the question marked as a duplicate as to some steps you might have followed/specified in your question, and the answer also suggesting to wait. (Note: please use only one user account for this site)