# Enabling HTTPS without impact on SEO

Tags: redirects, https

I'm planning to migrate all links on a site from HTTP to HTTPS in the near future. However, at the moment all I want to do is to enable HTTPS in order for it to be used on certain private areas of the site.

I've configured a new virtual host with the SSL certificates and the site now supports HTTPS. The old non-HTTPS URLs are working fine, too.

As it stands now, for the time being I don't want to issue any SEO-related changes therefore I haven't configured any 301 redirects to the new HTTPS URLs. Is there anything else I need to take care of in order for the HTTPS version of the site to remain invisible to search engines? I'd like to prepare for the migration and only issue the redirects when I'm ready.

Comment: Are the private areas of your site currently indexed in search? I assume that  private= login required.

Comment: No, they are not indexed and yes, they do require login.

Comment: In that case you don’t have to worry about it. Just set the ssl on the password protected sections. No seo impact.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Will do once I got out of this meeting.

Comment: Presumably, when you enable the SSL cert, you are enabling it for the entire site? Do you set _canonical_ URLs? If there is no explicit canonical (and pages don't have a bunch on inbound links) then Google will naturally _prefer_ the HTTPS version of the URL (if it is discovered). Stephen's answer to this question may be relevant: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110084/52912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sections you are concerned about are all password protected and not indexed in SERP then you don't have to worry about it.

Until you are ready to roll out SSL to the entire site (public and private sections), all you need to do is to make sure that https gets forced on the protected sections of the site only.