# GSC: Big changes in coverage of HTTP property after HTTPS migration. Is this acceptable?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, https, google-ranking

Some weeks ago, I migrated a 500k-webpage site from HTTP to HTTPS

- I implemented the appropriate 301 redirection
- I removed the sitemap of the HTTP property within Google Search Console

Today I found some abrupt changes in the figures of the coverage within Google Search Console:

- "Excluded: Page with redirect": boosted from 116k to 500k
- "Excluded: Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical": dropped from 500k to null
- "Excluded: Discovered - currently not indexed": dropped fron 500k to null
- "Error: Submitted URL seems to be a Soft 404": dropped from 20k to null

I would like to believe that these changes are the expected ones and are good for the ranking of my pages. Any similar experience would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case of Google moving your traffic over to HTTPS.

Your property that is verified in Google Search Console is a prefix property: `http://example.com`.   That will only show stats for the HTTP version of your site.   If you add a second prefix property for HTTPS (`https://example.com`) then you should see a growing number of indexed pages on that property.

You could also add a "domain property" in Google search console for `example.com`.  That will show all pages on both the `http` and `https` versions of your site.

On the other hand, there are often ranking and SEO problems when moving to HTTPS.   See [Are drops in Google ranking common after switching to https?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/106176/)   The safest way to move to HTTPS from an SEO standpoint is to run both HTTP and HTTPS simultaneously for a year and have canonical tags that point to HTTPS.  After a year, you can put in redirects to HTTPS.   Not all sites have problems with redirecting right away, but using the canonicals for a year seems to make the transition painless from a rankings standpoint.   See [my experience with moving my largest site to HTTPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110084) for more details.