# Large number of pages with "Alternate Page with Proper Canonical tag"

Tags: google-search-console

I am having this problem of "Alternate Page with Proper Canonical tag" on my website. Also there is another error in coverage "Duplicate without user-selected canonical". How to fix these?

Comment: Have you recently changed the URLs on your site?   I saw these coverage problems for a year after moving my site from HTTP to HTTPS.  See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110067/http-to-https-wait-for-new-sitemap-to-be-indexed/110084#110084

Comment: no i have not changed url

Answer (score 1):

If you post your actual loaded canonical tag I can help further or confirm any issues. This is a more complex issue with many possible issues.

But I just fixed a critical canonical issue with my own site and thought I'd post it for others.

I had been making my home page cannon URL like so:
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://aspectratia.com">`

A static canonical URL like above was **causing any URL with parameters to be disregarded** AKA indexed as non-canonical.

`https://aspectratia.com/?resx=1920&resy=1080&ratx=16&raty=9&page=1` = "Alternate page with proper canonical tag"

The fix was updating the canonical tag to include the params.

Why?

Because I want the URL with parameters to be considered unique pages since they define what unique content is shown.

`<link rel="canonical" https://aspectratia.com/?resx=1920&resy=1080&ratx=16&raty=9&page=1">`