# After adding HTTPS to my site, Google prefers to index HTTP

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, https, rel-canonical, yoast

I recently moved my website from HTTP to HTTPS. But when I try to get my HTTPS pages indexed, Google search console says "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical."

Google is preferring the HTTP version and indexing it but not the HTTPS. I tried adding user-declared canonical using the Yoast plugin but still, it is not getting indexed.

Should I redirect my entire website to HTTPS by editing the .htaccess file or is there any easier solution?

Comment: How long ago is "recently"?   It takes Google at least two weeks to react to changes and in my experience it can take a year to fully index a site on HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Comment: It has been over for 2 months. I have been requesting indexing but it's of no use. But the thing is I just want the major pages such as the service page, about page, and contact pages to be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You should leave the canonical tags in place with Yoast and hold off on doing redirects. Unfortunately, it will take up to a year for Google to index all your pages on HTTPS and there doesn't appear to be a way to speed that up that doesn't risk ranking drops.

When I migrated my largest site to HTTPS, I used canonical tags to do so.  It took a year, but otherwise the process went smoothly.  See my answer to [HTTP to HTTPS: Wait for new sitemap to be indexed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110067/http-to-https-wait-for-new-sitemap-to-be-indexed)

Implementing redirects from HTTP to HTTPS seems to cause ranking drops.  See [Are drops in Google ranking common after switching to https?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/are-drops-in-google-ranking-common-after-switching-to-https).  I would hold off on the redirects until Google indexes your HTTPS site.  Then it would be safe to put in the redirects.