# 301 redirect to HTTPS with back links to prevent ranking problems when moving from HTTP

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

Would like to ensure my sites rankings are not affected by doing the wrong type of redirect so I have a site that has been on non HTTPS since it was purchased many years ago. Now I'm looking to change it to HTTPS.

I have done a 301 permanent redirect on the site, this also includes all inner pages redirect to the HTTPS version. I have checked against redirect checkers found on the internet.

If there are external links which point to a certain page on the site (to help individual pages rank well) would this type of redirect cause any issues (mainly for back links on the site), Or would it adversely affect one of the new individual page's Google ranking?

Comment: See [Are drops in Google ranking common after switching to https?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/are-drops-in-google-ranking-common-after-switching-to-https).   Just issuing 301 redirects is not enough to prevent rankings problems in many cases.   I advocate running both HTTP and HTTPS side by side for a year while specifying the HTTPS URLs as the canonical.

Answer (score 3):

Back in 2014 it was reported that [Google was boosting encrypted websites](https://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2014/04/14/google-may-push-sites-to-use-encryption/) to encourage website owners to move their websites from HTTP To HTTPS.

Later on, they declared that they were [adjusting their indexing](https://security.googleblog.com/2015/12/indexing-https-pages-by-default.html) system to show search results with more pages using HTTPS.

People started to be concerned about using 301 Redirects as numerous tests showed, back in the day, that page rank was lost every time a page was redirected.

Then, Google released [this video](https://youtu.be/Filv4pP-1nw) to explain that no page rank is lost and that there's no extra value lost just because it is a 301.

Moreover, in this [Google guidelines on how to change your URLs with minimal impact](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049#https-faqs) including how to redirect your site from HTTP to HTTPS they wrote the following:

> **Do I lose credit for links when I redirect to new URLs?** No, 301 or 302 redirects do not cause a loss in PageRank

Now, back links will always lose link equity, the more a page has links the more the equity gets distributed and less “power” is pass to your pages. Whatever the power, authority, or value a link has will be carried over to the new HTTPS pages.

According to its official site you won’t be having any issue or lose your website or page rankings.

Answer (score 0):

301 redirects pass 95-100% page juice. So your backlinks pointing to your http urls will hold value, though it's possible it may lose a tiny bit through the 301. There's no need to update all of your backlink URLs unless it's rather easy for you to do so. The 301 will work.