# When redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, which URLs should be in the sitemaps?

Tags: 301-redirect, https, sitemap, http

Recently I've installed SSL certificate on my website and added a 301 redirection on my website for all links. Previously my sitemap included HTTP links and almost my 5000+ pages are now indexed on Google and my sitemap includes 13,000+ HTTP links.

Now my website has SSL installed and 301 redirects. Should I add HTTPS links to the same sitemap, will it affect my indexing in any way? Or should I continue submitting HTTP links and leave worry about it because my website now has 301 redirects for the whole website. Or should I create new sitemap for my website with all HTTPS links?

Comment: Put the https URLs in your sitemap instead of the http URLs. This shouldn't cause any deindexing. And the 301 redirect will naturally update the search URLs to https once Google crawls the 301s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google says that your sitemap [should only contain the version of the URLs you want indexed](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-sitemaps-no-variations-23125.html).   So you should take all your redirecting HTTP URLs out of your sitemap and replace them with your canonical HTTPS URLs.

When you move a site to HTTPS, [ranking drops are common](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/are-drops-in-google-ranking-common-after-switching-to-https) even with 301 redirects in place.   I'd recommend running both HTTP and HTTPS sites in parallel for a year and using canonical tags to point your site to the HTTPS version.   That is procedure I used for my largest site and I had no problems with the HTTPS migration.

Comment: What if I start adding https links to my current sitemap?

Comment: If i change all urls in my current sitemap, what happens the urls that are already indexed?

Comment: It is fine to change all the URLs in your current sitemap   Sitemaps don't usually effect how your site is indexed or ranked.   At most they help Google choose preferred URLs and give you extra stats about your site in Google Search Console.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: Would I also have to change the property on Google webmaster from HTTP to HTTPS property? Should I delete http property and add https property and submit my site with https links again?

Comment: You can add a second property on Google Search Console to see the stats about your HTTPS site.

Comment: So, should i duplicate my current sitemap and change all http links to https link and submit this new sitemap to https property?

Comment: Will it affect my indexing and something like that?

Comment: You can submit your sitemap to the new HTTPS property, it doesn't have to be duplicated to do that.  Neither registering in search console nor submitting your sitemap is likely to change how your site is indexed or ranked.

Comment: Yes, I have created a new https property and created a new sitemap with all https links.. But should i still update my old sitemap with http links?
 because it has redirection

Comment: If you have a new site map, you can just remove the old one.   You only need URLs in one sitemap and no sitemap should have redirecting URLs in it.

Comment: so deleting my old sitemap, will it affect my ranking?
 because links have been crawled from my previous sitemap?
or should i keep my old sitemap for sometime and not submit new urls in old sitemap

Comment: My old sitemap has redirecting urls, 
 but that is indexed
my point is that i will not submit new urls to my old sitemap

Comment: So now, should i delete old sitemap from my http property?

Comment: Deleting or changing your sitemap should never change how your site is indexed or ranked.   If you have your HTTPS URLs in a new sitemap, then go ahead and delete the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Update your sitemap with the https links. Also update the sitemap url in the robots.txt

I hope you also get to add a new property for the https verison of your website in Search console and update the sitemap there too

Comment: I have created a new property and hence a new sitemap with https links for this https site.